# Neo4j support for 50 TB db

Tags: sql, neo4j

I have a data intensive project for which I wrote the code recently, the data and sp live in a MS SQL db. My initial estimate is that the db will grow to 50TB, then it will become fairly static in growth. The final application will perform lots of row level look ups and readings, with a very small percentile of db write backs.

With the above scenario in mind, its being suggested that I should look at a NoSQL option in order to scale to the large load of data and transactions, and after a bit of research the roads leads to Neo4j (while considering MongoDB as a second alternative)

I would appreciate your guidance with the following set of initial questions:

-Does Neo4j support the concept of store procs? and does it supports conditional statements (if then, else, loops, etc)?

-Would I be able to install and run the 50TB db on a single node (single Windows Server)?

-Does Neo4j support/leverage multiple CPUs in single server (ex: 4 CPUs)?

-Would open source version be able to support the 50TB db? or would I need to purchase the ENT version?

Regards, 
-r

Comment: MS SQL will handle 50TB I have worked on a 275+ TB installation. Your biggest bottleneck here will be disk drives. Partitioning the table over multiple drives and making sure you have separate drives for indexes will help a lot with performance. You would need ENT version of SQL server though as it has a lot of the functions which is not available on Standard.

Comment: could you give examples of the data and queries you intend to run ? if they are basic index lookup of tabular data, then something like cassandra would be more appropriate for that kind of volume.

Comment: Hi bendaizer, the queries I intent to run are fairly straightforward Select statements in order to generate reports.  The blocker I found with Cassandra from what I understand, is that the lack of support ofstore procs and conditional statements within CQL, both of these are critical for my project.×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes.  Based on your recommendation to Cassandra, do I infer that Neo4j would not address the scenario I posted originally?

Comment: Hi Namphibian, thanks for the clarifications with regards to MS SQL, based on your comments from a real implementation (275+ TB), it is good to know that SQL Server can scale.  Perhaps I might keep with MS SQL, but, I am also looking at alternatives from the OSS community to understand licensing and cost options.

Comment: Hi bendaizer, reposting my reply without the edit errors.  The queries I intent to run are fairly straightforward Select statements in order to generate reports. The blocker I found with Cassandra from what I understand, is the lack of support for store procs and conditional statements within CQL, both of these are critical for my project. Based on your recommendation to look into Cassandra, do I infer that Neo4j would not address the scenario I posted originally?